# Evaluate $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{n}{(n-1)!}$.

Tags: summation

I realise this is quite simple, but I just don't exactly understand what the last step is. $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{n}{(n-1)!}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\frac{1}{(n-2)!}+\frac{1}{(n-1)!}\right)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{(n-2)!}+e$$

Answer (score 0):

In the last step, what happened is that the sum was broken into two. If you can prove the series converges, this is justified:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\frac{1}{(n-2)!}+\frac{1}{(n-1)!}\right)
= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(n-2)!}+ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(n-1)!} $$

Compare this last series with the Taylor series for $e^x$:

$$e^x = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{x^k}{k!}$$

Comment: But how can I evaluate the sum $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{(n-2)!}$ if (-1)! cannot be evaluated?

Comment: Think of $\dfrac{1}{(n-2)!}$ as $\dfrac{(n - 1)}{(n - 1)!}$ (which is where it comes from in the first step); the term is zero when $n = 1$, and so rewriting it as $\dfrac{1}{(n-2)!}$ is really only meaningful is $n \neq 1$.

Comment: Ah that makes sense. Thanks.